# Any dataset of tower crane sensor data

Tags: data-request, sensors

Are there any datasets available for ***tower crane*** sensor data? I need this data for my project. I searched around on the web but could not find any dataset specifically for that.

Comment: What sensors? Could be anything as it reads now: stress, hydraulic pressure, ...

Comment: @JanDoggen Every possible sensor that are on a tower crane. I just need an example sensor datasets that have been recorded from any single tower crane.

Comment: You have also not said what the *input* data is (sensors is just output). Some sort of load measurement probably? And in what format do you need the data, how much data? Please read [What a good request looks like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) If you tell people **what it's for** (instead of just 'my project'), that already explains a lot.